# Trimming data in R, getting rid of "*"

Tags: r, trim

I have a data set which looks like:

```
> data<-c( "IGHV1-2*02 F, or  IGHV1-2*03 F","IGHV3-23*01 F, or 
> IGHV3-23*04 F","IGHV2-70*01 F","IGHV7-4-1*01")
```

I would like to keep the first appearance of "V1-2" for example and delete anything which follows (including the "*").
So I tried the following:

```
> data.substr<-substr(data,4,9)
> data.substr1<-gsub("*","",data.substr)
```

but I still cant get rid of the "*", probably because it serves as a placeholder...
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You have to escape the * data.substr1<-gsub("[/*]","",data.substr)

Comment: Thank you very much Troy! Do you know an easier way to delete everything which follows the first asterisk (including it) and keeping the beginning?

Comment: This deletes everything wich follows the asterisk: data.substr1<-gsub("[/*]./*","",data.substr) (leaving out the "/")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
gsub("[*].*$","",data)
```

put `*` in square brackets, it will be treated as character, then any value `.*` until the end of the string `$` will be removed.